# How do you change the button touched colors in a ZoomButtonsController

Tags: android, button, controller, zooming

I am implementing a ZoomButtonsContainer in my app. It works well except that the color of the + and - buttons when pressed is a type of yellow ochre. I want to change this to reflect my app's colors. I'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

I have experimented with overwriting a number of the style properties in my activity's theme but none have any effect.I've tried the following:

```
 <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/plum</item>
 <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/plum</item>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by bypassing it with a more drastic solution which is even better. I've completely replaced the buttons with my own layout within the ZoomButtonsController. I show the code below in case this is of use to anyone.

Steps:

1. Create a layout for the buttons in my required style but with reference to the default layout used.
2. Create a background for the buttons to show the colors required for enabled/ pressed/ default.
3. Create a My_ZoomControls class using this layout, taking code as required from the default ZoomControls.
4. Create a My_ZoomButtonsController extended from ZoomButtonsController but referencing My_ZoomControls.
5. Initialize by switching out the default layout and replacing it with my customized one.
6. Include code to call setVisible(false) on detached from window and on visibility changed per the documentation for ZoomButtonsController.
7. Note that you need to take care with the controller "ownerView" per solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555482/making-androids-zoombuttonscontroller-and-gesturedetector-get-along)

zoom_contols.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_player_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ZoomButton
        android:id="@+id/zoomOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/zoom_controls_item_background"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/minus_circled"
        android:tint="@color/plum"/>

    <ZoomButton
        android:id="@+id/zoomIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/zoom_controls_item_background"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_circled"
        android:tint="@color/plum"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

zoom_contols_item_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/plum"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
        <padding android:bottom="2dp"
                 android:left="2dp"
                 android:right="2dp"
                 android:top="2dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/plum"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/plum_light"/>
        <padding android:bottom="2dp"
                 android:left="2dp"
                 android:right="2dp"
                 android:top="2dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/transparent"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
        <padding android:bottom="2dp"
                 android:left="2dp"
                 android:right="2dp"
                 android:top="2dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

My_ZoomControls

```
public class My_ZoomControls extends LinearLayout {

private final ZoomButton mZoomInButton;
private final ZoomButton mZoomOutButton;

public My_ZoomControls(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(false);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.zoom_controls, this, true);

    mZoomInButton = (ZoomButton) findViewById(R.id.zoomIn);
    mZoomOutButton = (ZoomButton) findViewById(R.id.zoomOut);
}

public void setOnZoomInClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    mZoomInButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

public void setOnZoomOutClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    mZoomOutButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}

public void setIsZoomInEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    mZoomInButton.setEnabled(isEnabled);
}

public void setIsZoomOutEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    mZoomOutButton.setEnabled(isEnabled);
}
```

}

My_ZoomButtonsController

```
public class My_ZoomButtonsController extends ZoomButtonsController {

private My_ZoomControls mControls;
private OnZoomListener mZoomListener;
private View.OnAttachStateChangeListener mAttachStateChangeListener;

public My_ZoomButtonsController(View ownerView) {
    super(ownerView);
}

public void setZoomControls(My_ZoomControls mControls) {
    this.mControls = mControls;
    this.mControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mZoomListener != null) mZoomListener.onZoom(true);
        }
    });
    this.mControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mZoomListener != null) mZoomListener.onZoom(false);
        }
    });
    this.mControls.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
            if (mAttachStateChangeListener != null) mAttachStateChangeListener.onViewAttachedToWindow(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
            if (mAttachStateChangeListener != null) mAttachStateChangeListener.onViewDetachedFromWindow(v);
        }
    });
}

public void setOnZoomListener(OnZoomListener listener) {
    mZoomListener = listener;
}

public void setOnAttachStateChangeListener(View.OnAttachStateChangeListener listener) {
    mAttachStateChangeListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void setZoomOutEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(enabled);
}

@Override
public void setZoomInEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(enabled);
}
```

}

Implementation. zoomInGrid is where I put my app specific code to zoom in.

```
private void setZoomButtonsController() {
    pZoomButtonsController = new My_ZoomButtonsController(pBtnSort);
    ViewGroup container = pZoomButtonsController.getContainer();
    View controls = pZoomButtonsController.getZoomControls();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = controls.getLayoutParams();
    container.removeView(controls);
    My_ZoomControls layout = new My_ZoomControls(My_Application_Base.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
    container.addView(layout, params);
    pZoomButtonsController.setZoomControls(layout);
    pZoomButtonsController.setOnZoomListener(new ZoomButtonsController.OnZoomListener() {

        @Override
        public void onZoom(boolean zoomIn) {
            zoomInGrid(zoomIn);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            if ((!visible) && (pZoomButtonsController != null)) {
                pZoomButtonsController.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
    pZoomButtonsController.setOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
            if (pZoomButtonsController != null) {
                pZoomButtonsController.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```